# Is there a way to copy the link URL in Safari (Mac OS X) without using right click?

Tags: safari

In Safari, if you want to copy the link URL, you should do 3 operations:

1. Hover the link
2. Right-click the link
3. Use the "Copy link" item from the main/contextual menu

Alternatively, you can hover/navigate to the link and then select the link (usually if textual) by using the mouse/trackpad. Then you hit CMD+C and have the link copied, but these are still 3 operations (navigate/hover, select, copy).

So, the question: Is there a way in Safari to reduce the above to just 2 operations:  **1) Hover** and **2) Copy** ?

It seems there are similar tools/plugins for Firefox and Chrome:

- Chrome: [Copy link address](https://github.com/dhruvvemula/copylinkaddress)
- Firefox: [Copy URL on Mouse Over](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/copy-url-on-mouse-over/?src=ss)

There is even a plugin for Safari which does something similar, but not exactly: *Type to navigate*. The issue is that this plugin is not designed to solve the above problem, so even though the plugin allows you to copy the link you have selected, it is not solving the real problem - how to reduce the steps to just 2 (hover and copy).

Ideas are welcome!

Comment: I came here looking for a solution for how to copy the URL of a google search results page.  Safari makes this difficult.  If you do what normally works, you just get the search terms.  Trying the answers now.  Currently, the trick in ughoavgfhw's answer doesn't work for me.  @Eric's DOES work for me.  (Odd - Slavic says it doesn't work.  I'm using Safari Version 11.1.2 (11605.3.8.1).  Confused.

Comment: You can reduce it to two operations: 1. Right click. 2. Copy link... No need for the "hover" step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do with the link, it may be sufficient to drag it. If you click and drag a link in Safari, you can drop it in many places and get the desired functionality. For example, if you drop it in a text editor, it will drop the link URL (for plain text) or a formatted link using the title from the page. If you drop it on your desktop, you will get a webloc file. If you drop it on the Safari URL bar or tab, that tab will load the link.

If you really need to copy the link, one possibility is to use spotlight as a easy-access text field. Start dragging the link, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (or whatever you have it set to) to pop up spotlight, drop it in the search field, and copy.

Comment: Thanks @ughoavgfhw - using drag & drop would certainly help!

Answer (score 7):

- Select <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
- That will highlight the URL field.
- Then just select <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.

This is the quickest keyboard shortcuts I have found.

Comment: What about Google search URLs? It will not work for them...

Comment: Bless you, you are a hero!  Command-L command-C.  I feel like I'm using emacs :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the [StopTheMadness](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stopthemadness/id1376402589?mt=12) extension (paid).

Simply hover on any link and press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. URL of the link will be copied to the clipboard.

It is available in the Mac App Store.

Comment: A link would be great!

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Done. Edited my earlier comment to add the link.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a wider description of your use case for this, or is this the only function you'd like to have in Safari?

i.e. You can use an Automator action to return all links and pass that to another action, if you are trying to pick up all links in a page via `Get Link URLs from Webpages` if you are attempting to automate grabbing links *in general*, not just the one you are hovering over.

Comment: I want to copy a specific (usually one or several, but not all) links from a given page and paste it in Mail.app. Imagine creating a status report via e-mail, in which you want to provide links (URLs) to the concrete issues in a web-based tracking system.

Comment: The Mac still relies on Drag and Drop, though a lot of this remains unspoken. Having two open app windows visible—-Safari and Mail, for example--allows drag and drop of not only links but images and sometimes text selections. Sometimes dropping on the Desktop as intermediate step--but experiment!

Comment: I have a rather specific scenario as well. When I want to share a page in Safari (Mac) my mind instantly gravitates to the Share menu, but if you've forgotten to copy the link prior to clicking share, you've added extra steps in the process. It would be fine if there were a subsequent keyboard shortcut, but alas, there is not. Would be great if there was a way to add this "Service" into the Share menu.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [Copy Link - Hover and Copy](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/copy-link-hover-and-copy/id6475746296) is what you want, a native MacOS Safari web extension which can copy the url with one click.